# Array intersection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am stumped on a question that prompts me to write a function in JavaScript that evaluates two arrays and returns a numerical value of how many matches the two arrays contain. it seems simple enough but after I write the loops in the function I'm not sure where to go.

this is what I've written:

```
function gradeQuiz(studentAnswers, teacherAnswers) {
  for (let i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length; i++) {
    let student = studentAnswers[i]
    for (let x = 0; x < teacherAnswers.length; x++) {
      let teacher = teacherAnswers[x]

    }
  }
}

gradeQuiz(["C","D","B"],["C","A","B"])
```

Comment: change  question title to array intersection

Comment: I know this is a total mess but I'm so confused and VERY new to coding

Comment: A couple things: You'll need to return a value from the function if you want to do anything with it. You're on the right track. You need to compare the `student` and `teacher` variables and add a match if they are the same.

Comment: @ashishsingh this is not intersection.

Comment: @Tajni how so ?

Comment: Maybe special kind of intersection, but definitely not normal intersection. Intersection doesn't mind order of the values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = ["string", "otherString"];
var array2 = ["string", "string"];

function matches(arr1, arr2) {
  var matches = 0; // Number of matches starts at 0
  // This will go over every 'combination' of values to look for matches
  arr1.forEach(item => { // For each item in the first array
    arr2.forEach(item2 => { // For each item in the second array
      if (item === item2) { // If the items match, add 1 to the counter
        matches += 1;
      }
    });
  });
  return matches // Once it's finished return how many matches there were
}
console.log(matches(array1, array2)); // Log it to the console so we can see
```

This iterates over every item in both array to check for matches. It's a simple function, but it works. Note that this works for more than just strings; it works for any types that can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

If the array length same, then you could simply do,

```js
const arr1 = [2,2,3]
const arr2 = [2,3,3]

const matches = arr1.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
    if (item === arr2[i]) acc++
    return acc
}, 0)

console.log(matches)  // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays (answers to questions by student and teacher are the same; which should be), a one-liner could be:

```js
student  = ["C","D","B"]
teacher  = ["C","A","B"]
var matched = 0

for (let i in student) {if (student[i] == teacher[i])  matched++;}

console.log(matched);       // 2
```

or as function:

```js
function matchedAnswers(student,teacher) {
  var matched = 0;
  for (let i in student) {if (student[i] == teacher[i])  matched++;}
  return matched;
}

console.log(matchedAnswers(["C","D","B"],["C","A","B"]))  // 2 answers matched
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods, `getScoredMarks` returns which vector of scores with corresponding places and `countGoodMarks` method return total number of good marks based on vector of scores.

```
var teacherMarks = ['C', 'D', 'B']
var studentMarks = ['C', 'A', 'B']

function countGoodMarks(scores) {
  return scores.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
}

function getScoredMarks(teacher,student) {
  return teacher.map((cur, index) => + (cur === student[index]))
}

console.log(getScoredMarks(teacherMarks, studentMarks)) //  [1 ,0 ,1] 
console.log(countGoodMarks(getScoredMarks(teacherMarks, studentMarks))) // 2
```